# A noun or an adjective for “No matter which religion you belong to you will be accepted”

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, adjectives

> Whether the sacred thread across the chest or the Qur'an in arms. The Lover is (a) _____, neither a Hindu nor a Muslim!

Whether he is wearing the sacred thread, or the Quran is in his hands; love is blind doesn’t see which religion you belong to. You will be accepted.

Comment: The Lover is **secular**, neither a Hindu nor a **Muslim**!  - (NB: secular is not a poetic/literary adjective.) The Lover is **of this world**, neither a Hindu nor a **Muslim**! (NB **of this world** is more poetic but a little old-fashioned.) Note "Musalman" has been obsolete since the 18th century

Comment: As you wrote: "love is blind".

Comment: I didn’t know that Musalman is obsolete. The way it is articulated in my mother tongue I wrote here. Thanks, though!